# C# Registry Import

Tags: c#, import, permissions, registry

I am trying to import a registry value that was saved previously thru C#.
Regedit runs each time I import, but the value doesnt change.  The only difference I get when running as administrator or not is the UAC prompt for regedit when not elevated.  Regedit still seems to run, but it seems to not be reading and importing the .reg file.

```
  Import:
        {

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                string FullPath = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(FullPath));

                Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s" + FullPath);
                regeditProcess.WaitForExit();
            }



            return;
        }
```

Comment: Check your FullPath. I believe there should also be a space after /s: "/s "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem could be if `FullPath` have spaces in it.
Instead of:

```
Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s" + FullPath);
```

try this:

```
Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s \"" + FullPath + "\"");
```

Comment: Cant cast a vote with low rep - but this was the answer.  Thanks!